# Remove duplicate of dict list

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I remove duplicates from the dict list below, while summing up the corresponding values thanks

```
{'VIC': [['City West ', 10.0], ['City West ', 30.0], ['Thornbury ',
         0.0]], 'NSW': [['Queanbeyan ', 5.0],['Queanbeyan ', 20.0]], 
         'ACT': [['Civic ', 8.0], ['Civic ', 60.0], ['Civic ', 1.0]]}
```

Desired output

```
{'VIC': [['City West ', 40.0], ['Thornbury ', 0.0]], 'NSW':
        [['Queanbeyan ', 25.0]], 'ACT': [['Civic ', 69.0]]}
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: See [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its examples in the docs. You just need to write a loop that creates a `Counter` for each list, and then loop over the name-value-pair sublists and does `my_counter[name] += value`. You should be able to write the rest yourself, but if you get stuck anywhere, you can ask for specific help.

Comment: please see revision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your desired output by using the following

```
dictionary = {'VIC': [['City West ', 10.0], ['City West ', 30.0], ['Thornbury ', 0.0]], 'NSW': [['Queanbeyan ', 5.0],['Queanbeyan ', 20.0]], 'ACT': [['Civic ', 8.0], ['Civic ', 60.0], ['Civic ', 1.0]]}

dic = {}
for i in dictionary:
    temp = {}
    for j in dictionary[i]:
        if not j[0] in temp: temp.update({j[0]: j[1]})
        else: temp[j[0]] += j[1]
    dic.update({i: [[j, temp[j]] for j in temp]})
dic
```

> {'ACT': [['Civic ', 69.0]], 
>  'NSW': [['Queanbeyan ', 25.0]], 
>  'VIC':
>   [['City West ', 40.0], ['Thornbury ', 0.0]]}

---

I would however suggest sing a dictionary of dictionaries for simplicity you can do the following

```
dictionary = {'VIC': [['City West ', 10.0], ['City West ', 30.0], ['Thornbury ', 0.0]], 'NSW': [['Queanbeyan ', 5.0],['Queanbeyan ', 20.0]], 'ACT': [['Civic ', 8.0], ['Civic ', 60.0], ['Civic ', 1.0]]}

dic = {}
for i in dictionary:
    temp = {}
    for j in dictionary[i]:
        if not j[0] in temp: temp.update({j[0]: j[1]})
        else: temp[j[0]] += j[1]
    dic.update({i: temp})

print(dic)
```

> {'ACT': {'Civic ': 69.0}, 
>  'NSW': {'Queanbeyan ': 25.0}, 
>  'VIC':
>   {'City West ': 40.0, 'Thornbury ': 0.0}}

Answer (score 4):

You can rebuilt the `dict` using dict-comprehension. During rebuilding, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the nested lists on first value of each sublist and sum the second value using a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> d = {'VIC': [['City West ', 10.0], ['City West ', 30.0], ['Thornbury ', 0.0]], 'NSW': [['Queanbeyan ', 5.0],['Queanbeyan ', 20.0]], 'ACT': [['Civic ', 8.0], ['Civic ', 60.0], ['Civic ', 1.0]]}
>>> {k:[[ke,sum([i[1] for i in list(g)])] for ke,g in groupby(sorted(v), key= lambda x: x[0])] for k,v in d.items()}
>>> {'NSW': [['Queanbeyan ', 25.0]], 'VIC': [['City West ', 40.0], ['Thornbury ', 0.0]], 'ACT': [['Civic ', 69.0]]}
```

The above expression can also be rewritten using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) instead of `lambda` to get some performance

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> {k:[[ke,sum([i[1] for i in list(g)])] for ke,g in groupby(sorted(v), key=itemgetter(0))] for k,v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my hat into the ring with defaultdict

```
In [6]: from collections import defaultdict

In [7]: tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

In [8]: a
Out[8]:  
{'ACT': [['Civic ', 8.0], ['Civic ', 60.0], ['Civic ', 1.0]],
 'NSW': [['Queanbeyan ', 5.0], ['Queanbeyan ', 20.0]],       
 'VIC': [['City West ', 10.0], ['City West ', 30.0], ['Thornbury ', 0.0]]}

In [9]: b = tree()

In [10]: for key in a:
    ...:     for entry in a[key]:
    ...:         if b[key][entry[0]]:
    ...:             b[key][entry[0]] += entry[1]
    ...:         else:                           
    ...:             b[key][entry[0]] = entry[1] 
    ...:                                         

In [11]: b
Out[11]:  
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'ACT': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
                         {'Civic ': 69.0}),                  
             'NSW': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
                         {'Queanbeyan ': 25.0}),             
             'VIC': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
                         {'City West ': 40.0, 'Thornbury ': 0.0})})

In [12]: c = {}

In [14]: for key in b:
    ...:     for entry in b[key]:
    ...:         if key in c:
    ...:             c[key].append([entry, b[key][entry]])
    ...:         else:
    ...:             c[key] = [[entry, b[key][entry]]]
    ...:

In [15]: c
Out[15]:
{'ACT': [['Civic ', 69.0]],
 'NSW': [['Queanbeyan ', 25.0]],
 'VIC': [['City West ', 40.0], ['Thornbury ', 0.0]]}
```

I've used a vivified hash map to do this, which in turns uses `defaultdict`. I like the automatic grouping feature it creates.